# Service web not work in device android

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, express, ionic-framework

I build Ionic app with node with express back-end , With this service i can fetch some json data using AngularJS http provider.
I can show the json data using browser.
But when i build my app and then install on my android device, nothing's shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to security. You may need to install cordova-plugin-whitelist and make the appropriate configurations - see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

If this is not the case please provide more details about the error you see in the console

Comment: So mainly id would be about the access origin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#network-request-whitelist. And you also need to set Content security policy if you already haven't done so: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy

Comment: I don't know how i can in-spectate when i run the app in the device u can help me.thinks